# Pantalla blanca al abrir mi app en android studio o en xCode

Tags: android-studio, angular, firebase, ionic, xcode

estoy creando una aplicación en ionic, utilicé firebase para hacer la autentificación de la app y cuando ejecuto el comando ionic serve -l se ve todo bien y funciona.

Después le puse el sdk y desplegué la aplicación, tanto en android como en ios, tuve un montón de errores, pero al final los solucioné y logré que se abriera la app en el simulador de android studio y de xCode, el problema es que todo en el móvil se visualiza correctamente, pero al momento de abrir mi aplicación se ve toda la pantalla en blanco y no puedo hacer nada. El xCode arroja un mensaje que dice "unsupported URL", "WebPageProxy::didFailProvisionalLoadForFrame" y "webview failed provisional navigation".

Es la primera vez que hago una aplicación con ionic, no sé si hay algo mal en la programación, en cómo puse el sdk, si falta hacer algo más, si tenía que enlazar la app a un dominio, o si la aplicación es pesada... sinceramente, no sé cuál podría ser el problema.

Agradecería muchísimo un poco de ayuda, gracias de antemano. Un saludo!!

Comment: Tienes en el `.plist` en Xcode este atributo `App Transport Security Settings` y dentro de este `Allow Arbitrary Loads` como `true`?

Comment: Try to build like this: ---> ionic build --prod --platform=ios